# Getting all the values inside the Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that has multiple input fields. My HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="mainDiv">
  <input type="text" id="price" /> <br/>
  <input type="text" id="tax" />
  <input type="text" id="others" />
</div>
<img src="img/img.gif" onclick="getAllValues();" />
```

After I click the image, it must get all the values inside the `mainDiv`. How can I do this?

Comment: Your number of inputs is fixed in three?

Comment: All the `input` elements have `id` attributes, so you can select them directly. Your question statement implies that you have multiple elements with the same `id`, which is invalid and is a problem you need to fix.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#getallvalues").click(function() {

  var values = $("#mainDiv input").map(function() {
    return $(this).val()
  }).get().join(",");

  console.log(values)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainDiv">
  <input type="text" id="price" /> <br/>
  <input type="text" id="tax" />
  <input type="text" id="others" />
</div>
<img src="img/img.gif" id="getallvalues" />
```

Loop through each input then get the value and use `.map()`

```js
var price = 0;
var tax = 0;
var others = 0;
$("#getallvalues").click(function() {

  $("#mainDiv input").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "price") {

      price = $(this).val()

    }
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "tax") {

      tax = $(this).val()

    }

    if ($(this).attr("id") == "others") {

      others = $(this).val()

    }

  })

  console.log("price " + price)
  console.log("tax " + tax)
  console.log("others " + others)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainDiv">
  <input type="text" id="price" /> <br/>
  <input type="text" id="tax" />
  <input type="text" id="others" />
</div>
<img src="img/img.gif" id="getallvalues" />
```

Comment: i want to store every value in a variable sir, how do u do that?

Comment: if you can have a variable for each then since you have unique ID for each check the id if equal to something put it to its variable @ry-el

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map()` to iterate over element and return the value in call back along with `.get()` to get them in array:

```
function getAllValues(){
  $('#mainDiv input').map({
     return this.value;
  }).get();  // Output: ["priceval","taxval","otherval"]
}
```

You can use above array to create the data in whichever format(csv,json,etc) you want for further processing.

Comment: how about storing it directly in a variable sir? how to do that?

Comment: In a comma separated format or in array? for array you can assign the result of above expression to variable. For csv add `.join(",")` after `.get`

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all the inputs in mainDiv

```
$('#mainDiv input').each(function(){
// Do what ever
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is like follows:

`$('#mainDiv').find('input').each(function (index, element) {
    var yourValue = element.value; // or $(element).val();
    // And rest of your code
});`

Comment: whats the use of index?

Comment: Index is the array index, It can be used, if you want to get a specific element from the array. `$('#mainDiv').find('input')` this will give you an array of `input` from the div.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#mainDiv input').each(function(){
   console.log(this.val());
})
```